# For a Mac error how do you determine the object when given its hex ID?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have been given an error on the Mac:

```
objc[30344]: FREED(id): message release sent to freed object=0x3d55b60
```

How do I determine the object's symbolic identity so that I can fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to get the symbol that the object is associated with.  For this kind of thing you'll likely want to use [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/) to track down where the object was allocated.